# How to register a Web User only (without a lotus notes id file) in Domino Directory

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus-domino, lotusscript

I have a Lotus Notes web application where users are required to be defined in the same database using a custom profile form. Specific roles will be assigned in every user accordingly based on the selected predefined user roles. These users will be populated in the ACL dynamically using lotus script web agent.
My question is, how do I programatically register the user in the domino directory? Can I just create a person document with basic info and internet password and assign an external email like gmail or yahoo? If it's possible, do I still need to certify the user using the Certifier Id?

Your suggestion is very much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don’t need to certify the user or create an id file. As you already suggested, you just create the person document in the directory database. Look at [Registering users for your Domino Web site](http://second-ext.inttrust.ru/Lotus/NotesWeb/Today.nsf/99ede8829c8ac8e8852563e100727d67/693ef4c5d60c01fb8525659a0057ceb3?OpenDocument) for details, e.g. how to avoid duplicate user names.

Comment: The database where the users are to be created needs to be recognised as a 'directory' database. This used to be called 'directory assistance' (DA) but I think this changed some time ago. You can't just create 'person' docs in any database.